# Sylius - How to define product with options that have impact on price?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

In Sylius I can create variant of of a product, for instance 3 sizes of a t-shit, each size have different price. This is a nice solution if I have a product with one thing that has an impact on a price.

What about situation, where I have a Tshirt which have many options that have an impact on price, like:

- Size
- Material
- Color
- and few more

I cannot create product with variants, of each configuration. It should be for example in a way, that this particular option has an impact on price by adding to it some amount of money or %. This is like Adjustment, I think. But how to use it for products?

----MORE DETAILS--------
I need to define a product with some options that have impact on price, like Adjustments. Then when User adds product to cart, he/she chooses some options. Each of these options changes the product price. So base product has price $20. But when user adds it to cart, change 3 parameters, then the price should be $35. And this product with $35 price should be added to a cart, and then to an order.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider listening to product or variant post create event, then in your listener check what options are set and adjust price according to options.

Comment: I think my description was not correctly written. I need to define a product with some options that have impact on price, like Adjustments. Then when User adds product to cart, he/she chooses some options. Each of these options changes the product price. So base product has price $20. But when user adds it to cart, change 3 parameters, then the price should be $35. And this product with $35 price should be added to a cart, and then to an order.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can use custom PriceCalculator which must use [CalculatorInterface](https://github.com/Sylius/Pricing/blob/master/Calculator/CalculatorInterface.php).
In this class could be implemented all custom logic which depend of product.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on the answer.